# Проблема с MySQL и PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Вот такой вот код в PHP:

```
<?php
            $link = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM games WHERE id = 1");

            echo $link;
?>
```

Дело в том, что echo $link в этом случае выводит такое значение: Resource id #17.

Такого в моей БД нет и не может быть.

А когда я пишу в PHPMyAdmin SQL эту же строку, мне выдаёт правильное значение.

Скорее всего это проблема PHP.

Подключился к БД я правильно, вот код:

```
<?php
        mysql_connect(
        "localhost",
        "***********",
        "******"
                        );
        mysql_select_db("************") or die(mysql_error());


    ?>
```

Comment: такие вопросы здесь уже были (один из них не так давно), надо было [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) читать и смотреть примеры. Сейчас у вас все правильно показывает

Comment: раз уж я сходил по ссылке)) "Полученный дескриптор результата нужно передать в функцию mysql_fetch_assoc() или любую другую функцию, работающую с результатами запросов."

Comment: Скорее всего это проблема PHP >>>>>>>>> Это проблема НЕ PHP. Это проблема неполного изучения документации с примерами ВАМИ

Answer (score 3):

У Вас PHP всё выводит абсолютно верно. Это дескриптор результата (см. [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)), который необходимо передать в другую функцию, которая собственно и будет его обрабатывать. Эти функции также упоминаются в документации по ссылке.

**P.S.**
Для работы с MySQL  настоятельно советую отказаться от использования одноимённого расширения PHP. Начиная с версии 5.5 оно официально объявлено устаревшим и само его наличие в последующих версиях не гарантируется. Используйте MySQLi или PDO.